# Count IF with Unique in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, unique, formula, countif, formulas

I'm having trouble completing formulas that combine COUNT IF with UNIQUE in Sheets.

This is my current formula, which works fine.

```
=COUNTIFS($AD:$AD,"Tour Operator",$AA:$AA,"DG",$AL:$AL,"Booked",$AM:$AM,I2)
```

I now need to add to it to only count if the entry in $AC:$AC is unique. How can this be done?

Further to this, how can it be adapted to ONLY count if two columns are unique, so the same formula as above but both $AC:$AC and $AM:$AM must be unique together to count as 1. To explain, the example below should count 3 unique entries.

`AC       AM
test1   unique1
test1   unique1
test1   unique2
test2   unique3
test2   unique3`

Thanks for any help, hope I've been clear enough in explaining.

Answer (score 1):

`=UNIQUE()` can take in an array, so take advantage of that, but this will also return the blank rows (if any). Then use `ROWS()` to count the results. Since you're looking at two rows that aren't adjacent to each other, you'll need to combine them using curly braces. Since `UNIQUE()` may have returned an empty row, you can simply subtract by 1.

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE({$AC:$AC,$AM:$AM}))-1
```

Since it's not guaranteed that AC or AM will have blank rows, you could also filter out those blank rows:

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE({FILTER($AC:$AC, NOT(ISBLANK($AC:$AC))),FILTER($AM:$AM, NOT(ISBLANK($AM:$AM)))}))
```